# Как выделить строки таблицы цветом при нажатии мышкой в Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap

Как выделить строки таблицы цветом при нажатии мышкой в Bootstrap? Может какое-нибудь свойство указать? Или нужно прописывать программно?

Comment: Цвет нужно сохранять после отпускания мышки? Распишите более подробно вопрос и что вы попробовали сделать сами.

Comment: $('tr').on('click', function(){ $(this).addClass('my-clicked-row')})

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать jQuery примерно так:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('tr').click(function(){
        $('tr').removeClass();
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    });
});
</script>
```

И CSS:

```
<style>
.selected{ background: silver;}
</style>
```

Если нужно выделять несколько строк, предлагаю воспользоваться
Google Charts: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/table
Пример использования: https://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/